# How to remove whitespace of a substring

Tags: javascript, string, trim, removing-whitespace

I am working on a functional programming exercise and I was asked to replace all whitespaces in the string with an hyphen. If I have a string like `This is a title`, the output should be `this-is-a-title`.

Now, all cases as described before work but I have an edge case string like this:  `Peter Is  Coming`. I would like to strip out the whitespace that is before the `Coming` so that my final output is `peter-is-coming` which would be the equivalent output for when I have an initial string of `Peter is Coming` with no redundant whitespace. I was able to do that of before `Peter` with ease using the `trim` method. How do I go about this edge case's?

Note: One of the constraints is that there shouldn't be the use of the `replace` method.

Thanks.

My code:

```
function urlSlug(title) {

  const url = title.trim().toLowerCase();
  console.log(url);

  const splitURL = url.split("");
  // console.log(splitURL);

  const urlArr = [];

  const filtered = splitURL.filter(val => {
    if (/\s/.test(val)) {
      
      urlArr.push("-");
    }
    
    else {
      urlArr.push(val);
    }
  });

  return console.log(urlArr.join(""));

}

urlSlug("A Mind Needs Books Like A Sword Needs A Whetstone"); // a-mind-needs-books-like-a-sword-needs-a-whetstone
urlSlug("Hold The Door"); // hold-the-door 
urlSlug(" Peter is  Coming"); // peter-is--coming 

// The last output is what I get but not what I want to achieve.
```

**Update**:

Thanks to everybody that answered. I eventually used the code below in relation to my original code and it passed the edge case:

```
function urlSlug(title) {

  const url = title.trim().toLowerCase();
  console.log(url);

  const splitURL = url.split(/\s+/);
  // console.log(splitURL);

  const urlArr = [];

  const filtered = splitURL.filter(val => {
    if (/\s/.test(val)) {
      
      urlArr.push("-");
    }
    
    else {
      urlArr.push(val);
    }
  });

  return console.log(urlArr.join("-"));

}
```

Answer (score 2):

**You can create a new variable `previousWhiteSpace` that keeps track of whether the previous iteration of .filter() resulted in whitespace.**

Using your current implementation, this doesn't take much of a change (note `previousWhiteSpace`):

```
function urlSlug(title) {
  const url = title.trim().toLowerCase();
  console.log(url);

  const splitURL = url.split("");
  // console.log(splitURL);

  const urlArr = [];

  let previousWhiteSpace = false;

  const filtered = splitURL.filter(val => {
    if (/\s/.test(val)) {
      // after making sure val is whitespace, pass harmlessly if previous val was whitespace
      if (!previousWhiteSpace) {
        urlArr.push("-");
        previousWhiteSpace = true;
      }
    }
    else {
      urlArr.push(val);
      previousWhiteSpace = false;
    }
  });

  return console.log(urlArr.join(""));
}

urlSlug("A Mind Needs Books Like A Sword Needs A Whetstone"); // a-mind-needs-books-like-a-sword-needs-a-whetstone
urlSlug("Hold The Door"); // hold-the-door 
urlSlug(" Peter is  Coming"); // peter-is-coming
```

**However, this can be vastly simplified by splitting `url` with a whitespace character (`\s`) instead of `""`, saving you an extra iteration with `filter`.**

*Example:*

```
function urlSlug(title) {
  const url = title.trim().toLowerCase();

  // whitespace regex to match every whitespace character
  const urlArr = url.split(/\s+/);

  return console.log(urlArr.join("-"));
}

urlSlug("A Mind Needs Books Like A Sword Needs A Whetstone"); // a-mind-needs-books-like-a-sword-needs-a-whetstone
urlSlug("Hold The Door"); // hold-the-door 
urlSlug(" Peter is  Coming"); // peter-is-coming
```

**EDIT: Because it's Javascript, why not take it even further?**

*Single line solution:*

```
const urlSlug = (title) => console.log(title.trim().toLowerCase().split(/\s+/).join("-"));

urlSlug("A Mind Needs Books Like A Sword Needs A Whetstone"); // a-mind-needs-books-like-a-sword-needs-a-whetstone
urlSlug("Hold The Door"); // hold-the-door 
urlSlug(" Peter is  Coming"); // peter-is-coming
```

Comment: Single-line solution for fun: 

`const urlSlug = (title) => console.log(title.trim().toLowerCase().split(/\s+/).join("-"));`

Comment: This comment is the best answer and should be _your_ answer +1.

Answer (score 1):

The condition `if (/\s/.test(val))` doesn't consider consecutive *whitespace* characters between words.

You can try the following way:

```js
function urlSlug(title) {
  //remove leading and trailing spaces
  //convert to lowercase
  const trimmedTitle = title.trim().toLowerCase();

  //split words array
  const words = trimmedTitle.split(/\s+/);

  //join the words with hyphens
  const slug = words.join("-");

  return slug;
}

console.log(urlSlug("A Mind Needs Books Like A Sword Needs A Whetstone")); //a-mind-needs-books-like-a-sword-needs-a-whetstone
console.log(urlSlug("Hold The Door")); //hold-the-door 
console.log(urlSlug(" Peter is  Coming")); //peter-is-coming
```

Comment: That actually works. Thanks. Seems like I don't need the filter method after all.

Comment: @Hi-P, yes, `join()` does the trick:)

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue, you can use the split method to break the string into words, and then use join to concatenate them with hyphens. This way, redundant spaces are automatically removed.

```
    function urlSlug(title) {
      const url = title.trim().toLowerCase();
      const splitURL = url.split(/\s+/);
      return splitURL.join("-");
    }

    console.log(urlSlug("A Mind Needs Books Like A Sword Needs A Whetstone")); // a-mind-needs-books-like-a-sword-needs-a-whetstone
console.log(urlSlug("Hold The Door")); // hold-the-door
console.log(urlSlug(" Peter is  Coming")); // peter-is-coming
```

Here, /\s+/ in the split function means that it will break the string at any amount of white space, thus removing redundant spaces. Then join concatenates the words with hyphens, solving your edge case.